# Jquery Slide problem

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code and want a panel on my page to slide when a link is clicked.

But the problem is that the page jumps to the top.
Is there any way to stop the page from jumping to the top?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("[href='#']").click(function(){
        $("#message_panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
```

Here's the code I have somewhere down on the same page.

```
<a href="#" ><span>more</span></a>
       <div id="message_panel" class="nodisplay">
        message here.
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("[href='#']").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

        $("#message_panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[href='#']").click(function(e){   
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#message_panel").slideToggle("slow");       
});
```

e.preventDefault() should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The jumping issue is because you are using '#' as the link. Start using `Javascript:void(0)` in those cases instead.